# how to make use of code reuse in c#?

Tags: c#

I have 1 solution,
2 projects p2p,member,
2 namespaces p2p and member respectively in them,
how do I make use of the class defined in p2p namespace in members main routine?

I am new to c# and have hacked my way till here in 2 days.
I used c# just to port my c++ program to it as it saves lots of time using .NET code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reference to the p2p project in the member project, then type

```
using p2p;
```

at the beginning of your member code

Answer (score 0):

This should tell you how to do what you are looking for:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/34528

Answer (score 0):

When using visual studio you can add a reference to the p2p project from members. 
(Right click on the project and select add reference).

After that you can access the members of p2p by prefixing it with the namespace or by adding a using clause to the file you're working in.